# Meaning of a software update message and warning

Tags: updates

I just got this update message which includes a warning.

[image]

As this is the first time I see it I would like to know what it means. Also given that this is about a security update I understand that it is important, but why?

Comment: @NickWeinberg How do you find duplicates like this one that has such a title? :P Thanks though!

Comment: I want to know that too. I always wondered.

Comment: @Adam @Kev Inski Sometimes I search google for `searchterm site:askubuntu.com` or use askubuntu's own search feature. In this case, i remembered seeing that other question earlier today and that it contained the term `EOL`. Sure enough, when I searched this site for `EOL` and sorted by new, it was the first result!